# C# How to eliminate duplicate values from comboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox, duplicates, oledbdatareader

I would like to eliminate duplicates from OleDbDataReader
Should be easy but I'm spinning my wheels. Any help would be appreciated!

```
        private void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from PPAPdatabase";
                command.CommandText = query;                

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox_Owner.Items.Add(reader["Owner"].ToString());                   
            }
```

Comment: why an additional reader? why not the same datatable?

Comment: I'd use the database to do that for you. Just write a suitable select distinct query for it. You could do it in code using LINQ, but there's no point in this example. e.g. `select distinct Owner from PPAPdatabase where Owner is not null`

Comment: Clear the ComboBox first near the top of your method using `comboBox_Owner.Items.Clear()`, then amend your SQL to be `select distinct Owner from PPAPdatabase where Owner is not null`. And you only need to fill the datasource once, you don't really require to do the reader as well. Use either the reader or the datasource method. Job done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your SQL query like this :

```
select distinct Owner from PPAPdatabase
```

Instead of

```
select * from PPAPdatabase
```

The only column you need in your code is Owner then get that only one column and apply DISTINCT clause to it to get distinct value for that column.

Or replace the following lines :

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    comboBox_Owner.Items.Add(reader["Owner"].ToString());                   
}
```

By this :

```
var owners = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Owner"].ToString()).Distinct();
foreach(var owner in owners)
{
    comboBox_Owner.Items.Add(owner);                   
}
```

In this solution we're using one SQL Query to your Database and reuse the result to extreact distinct owners.

Comment: Correct me I am wrong but I used **string query = "select * from PPAPdatabase";** to show all data in datagridview.

Comment: @NOGRP90 Then you might create separate command. Each command has its own SQL query.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Could you please write it?

Comment: @adjan Clear the combobox prior to population from the database, of course.

Comment: @NOGRP90 I updated my answer then for another better way.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thank you so much!

Comment: @NOGRP90 If it works then you must accept it as an answer I Think :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Can I use "var owners =..." more time for another combobox? Just replace the owners.

Comment: Then you must declare the local variable `owners` as a field of your class.

Comment: For example: I have a **"comboBox_Pline"** and another 2 textbox. Could you please show me how to do that? I am newbie in programming. I would really appreciate.

Comment: You will do the same foreach instruction that you do with your comboBox_Owner combobox.

Comment: If `owners` if a field on your class. Just od this
 `foreach(var owner in this.owners)
{
    comboBox_Pline.Items.Add(owner);                   
}`

Comment: @CodeNotFound You look proficient. Are you able to solve my another question?? :)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048713/c-sharp-how-to-store-selected-checkedlistbox-values-in-different-columns-in-ms

Answer (score 2):

you can do this way

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (!comboBox_Owner.Items.Contains(reader["Owner"].ToString()))
        comboBox_Owner.Items.Add(reader["Owner"].ToString());                  
}
```

Comment: It would be better to clear the combobox and populate it from distinct values from the database, as suggested in other answers. That's the correct solution for you.

Comment: @ManoDestra Yes. It would be but I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: I've added the technique as a comment to the question itself.